# How to check if arguments is passed to a function in C?

Tags: c, arguments

I don't know how to fill up the sentence "if initial_value is passed".
Do I have to use the variable argument? It isn't very readable to me, so I'm finding out other methods.

Help me please..

```
int *func (int initial_value) {
    int *number;

    number = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if ("if initial_value is passed") *number = initial_value;
    else scanf("%d", &number);

    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C (and C++) calling a funciton without its parameters will result in a compile time error. So the function cannot be called without the parameter.

I think what you are looking for are [default arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments), which is a C++ feature. It is not available in normal C.

A way to implement something similar in C is possible through pointers:

```
int * func (int * initial_value) {
    int x;
    if( initial_value == NULL ) {
        x = 5;
    } else {
        x = *initial_value;
    }
    //...more code and return
}

//when you call it use:
func( NULL ); // x = 5
int arg = 7;
func( &arg ); // x = 7
```

Side note:

```
scanf("%d", &number); -> scanf("%d", number); //because number already is a pointer
```